# How can I generate a plot similar to that produced by plot.bugs and plot.jags from an mcmc.list?

Tags: r, data-visualization, jags, bugs

R seems to be able to output nice summary plots from the `bugs` and `jags` objects generated by the functions [R2WinBUGS::bugs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/index.html) and [R2jags:jags](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2jags/index.html).

However, I am using the [`rjags`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/index.html) package. When I try to plot the results of the function `rjags::coda.samples` using `R2WinBUGS::plot.mcmc.list` the results are diagnostic plots (parameter density, chain time series, autocorrelation) for each parameter.

Below is the type of plot that I would like to produce, from Andrew Gelman's tutorial ["Running WinBuugs and OpenBugs from R"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/runningbugs.html). These were produced by using the `plot.pugs`.

The problem is that `plot.bugs` takes a `bugs` object as an argument, while `plot.mcmc.list` takes the output of `coda.samples`.

Here is an example (from the `coda.samples`):

```
 library(rjags)
 data(LINE)
 LINE$recompile()
 LINE.out <- coda.samples(LINE, c("alpha","beta","sigma"), n.iter=1000)
 plot(LINE.out)
```

What I need is either

- a way to generate a similar, information-rich, one-page summary plot similar to the one produced by `plot.bugs`
- a function that will convert `LINE.out` to a bugs object or

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no answers, I will at least post what I have gotten so far:

The `as.bugs.array` function in the `R2WinBUGS` package was created for this purpose. According to the documentation (`?as.bugs.array`):

> Function converting results from Markov chain simulations, that might not be from BUGS, to bugs object. Used mainly to display results with plot.bugs.

Thus, it is possible to obtain a plot from `LINE.out` in your example, although it does not plot the correct variables:

```
plot(as.bugs.array(sims.array = as.array(LINE.out)))
```

It will take a little bit more work to determine the correct way to transform the `LINE.out`, and the `LINE.samples` object from `example(jags.samples)` may be an easier place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me:

```
require(R2jags)
m <-jags(data=d,inits=i,pars,n.iter=1000,n.chains=3,model.file="foo.txt",DIC=F)
m <- autojags(m)
plot(m)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
example(jags)
plot(jagsfit)
```

Comment: That is a helpful clue, but doesn't solve the problem of starting with an `mcmc.list` (as far as I can tell).